# pyqt5 - how to find menu in menubar:

Tags: pyqt5

I'm running a  code that adds a menu to the toolbar.
But when I run it again, it adds another menu to the toolbar with the same name.

How do I get rid of the first menu?
I found "setVisible=True", but I don't know how to find the menu whom I should set this to. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

```
def run(self)
     with open(menubar_file) as file:
            yaml_content = file.read()
            menu_dict = yaml.load(yaml_content, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
     for menu, menubar_content in menu_dict.items():
            q_menubar = self.win.menubar.addMenu(menu). // How do I do "if self.win.menubar contains menu, delete(menu)?"
            # rest of code
```

Couldn't find it in the documentation...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are various possibilities, but if you are doing this only for a top level menu, why don't you just store them in a list or set? If you then call the function again, just check if the menu title is already in the list/set.

Comment: @musicamante You're right - it is a possibility, the thing is that it's not my code and I'm part of a messy corporate code, so I'm thinking if there's any default way to achieve that.

Comment: I can't write a complete answer right now, but in the meantime remember that every widget has access to its [`actions()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#actions) and when you add a menu (or submenu), you add an action to its parent, which is the [`menuAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction) for that menu. Begin reading those parts of the documentation (which are very important to know anyway), I'll add an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Every QWidget has a list of QActions, they are normally added using [`addAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction) or [`addActions()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addActions), but QMenu and QMenuBar do that also when using `addMenu()`.

Each QMenu also has a [`menuAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction), which is the action used when the menu is added to a QMenuBar or to QMenu as a sub menu.

Using [`actions()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#actions) you can access the list of each action added to a certain widget, and in the case of QMenuBar it will list every `menuAction()` of each menu.

Note that:

- you can add basic QActions to a QMenuBar (it will not be a menu, and clicking it will trigger the action);
- adding actions to widgets doesn't change their ownership, as the same action can be shared between multiple widgets;
- the opposite of `menuAction()` is [`menu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#menu), which returns the QMenu associated with that action;

If you need to replace each existing menu based on its title, you can cycle through all actions, check if the name matches and it's a menu, and then clear it before replacing its contents:

```py
def run(self)
    with open(menubar_file) as file:
        yaml_content = file.read()
        menu_dict = yaml.load(yaml_content, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

    menus = {a.text():a.menu() for a in self.win.menubar.actions() if a.menu()}
    for menu_name, menubar_content in menu_dict.items():
        menu = menus.get(menu_name)
        if menu is None:
            self.win.menubar.addMenu(menu_name)
        else:
            menu.clear()
        # ...
```